# Android Lint Message: Update to Fragment 1.3.0 to use ActivityResult API error in Analysis/ Inspect Code

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

When running Android Studio/ Analyze/ Inspect Code...
I get 50+ identical error messages "Android/Lint/Correctness Error
Upgrade Fragment version to at least 1.3.0" on this line of code:

```
class MainActivity :  AppCompatActivity() {...

registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->...
```

The code breaks on breakpoints, so code is called and the application works correctly.

Build gradle includes (Kotlin language)

```
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.1"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.1"
debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.1"
```

I want to FIX the error message (not hide it). Since the code works correctly, and I use fragment-ktx:1.3.1 what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported on Google's Issue Tracker and, I quote:

> This has been fixed internally and will be available in the next Activity release.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182388985#comment9

Comment: I still get this lint error tho, even after changing it to `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-alpha07` and `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3`